# Is x%(1e9 + 7) and x%(10**9 + 7) different in Python? If yes, why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point

For an integer x, `x % (10 ** 9 + 7)` and `x % (1e9 + 7)` are giving different results after a few iterations. To reproduce this results, I am sharing my solution for [LeetCode #576. Out of Boundary Paths](https://leetcode.com/problems/out-of-boundary-paths/). My solution won't pass 5 out 94 test cases if I change `return ans % (10 ** 9 + 7)` to `return ans % (1e9 + 7)` (realising this took me an hour).

Note that this solution is much longer than one-liner presented by some genius guy [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/out-of-boundary-paths/discuss/102975/Python-1-line-solution). However, the same problem arises with his solution if we change `% (10 ** 9 + 7)` to `% (1e9 + 7)`.

I played a bit with the  python compiler and noticed that 1e9 gives a float literal. So it seems to me that this peculiarity is caused by 'weirdness' of floating point arithmetic. But I still don't understand how a zero after decimal point can cause difference. Why is this difference arising?

Without reproducing, differences can be found here : https://www.diffchecker.com/PyKQCElB

To reproduce, here's my solution :

```py
class Solution:
    def findPaths(self, m: int, n: int, maxMove: int, startRow: int, startColumn: int) -> int:
        if maxMove == 0:
            return 0
        current_state = [[0 for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(m)]
        next_state = [[0 for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(m)]
        current_state[startRow][startColumn] = 1
        ans = self.count_ways(m, n, current_state)
        
        k = 1
        while k < maxMove:
            # print("CS:", current_state)
            for i in range(m):
                for j in range(n):
                    next_state[i][j] = 0
                    if i != 0:
                        next_state[i][j] += current_state[i-1][j]
                    if i!= m-1:
                         next_state[i][j] += current_state[i+1][j]
                    if j != 0:
                        next_state[i][j] += current_state[i][j-1]
                    if j != n-1:
                        next_state[i][j] += current_state[i][j+1]
            
            current_state, next_state = next_state, current_state
            ans += self.count_ways(m, n, current_state)
            
            # print("NS:", current_state)
            # print("k:{},ans:{}".format(k, int(ans % 10 ** 9 + 7)))            
            # print("k:{},ans:{}".format(k, int(ans % 1e9 + 7)))            

            k += 1
            
        # return ans % (1e9 + 7)  # This is giving incorrect results.
        return ans % (10 ** 9 + 7)  # This works fine.
        
    def count_ways(self, m, n, grid):
        ways = 0
        for i in range(m):
            for j in [0, n-1]: # Checking left and right strips of a grid.
                ways += grid[i][j]
                 
        for j in range(n):
            for i in [0, m-1]: # Checking top and bottom strips of a grid.
                ways += grid[i][j]
                
        # This will automatically add corner boxes twice.
        
        return ways
```

EDIT : Use this test case (arguments to `findPaths`, in order) :

```
36
5
50
15
3
```

Comment: In the docs here https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=exponent#numeric-types-int-float-complex there is this line `"Numeric literals containing a decimal point or an exponent sign yield floating point numbers."`. If you've been on stackoverflow long enough I'm sure you've seen this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken linked

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> But I still don't understand how a zero after decimal point can cause difference.

Where the decimal point isn't important. It's floating!

> Why is this difference arising?

Because floating point numbers in Python are the usual hardware ones which means they have limited storage and precision:

```
>>> int(123123123123123123123.0)
123123123123123126272
#                ^^^^ different!
```

But integer numbers in Python have infinite storage and precision ("bignum"):

```
>>> int(123123123123123123123)
123123123123123123123
```

So:

```
>>> 123123123123123123123 % 10**9
123123123

>>> 123123123123123123123 % 1e9
123126272.0
```

In the second case both sides are converted to floating point because one of them is.

Comment: I didn't understand why int(something.0) is not something, your edit made it clear.

Comment: @Deep glad it helped!